# Disable system crontab job in Magento

Tags: magento, cron

Is it possible to disable system crontab job (for example "catalog_product_index_price_reindex_all" from Mage_Catalog) via `app/etc/local.xml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say to avoid hacking the shell indexer or the core.

Create a custom module and rewrite the schedule to run for example on the 31st of February (which will never occur).

Or if you want to disable it globally, and avoid running it even when you really need a reindex all, then just overwrite the `catalog/observer` observer model and add your `reindexProductPrices()` method where you just return out of the method.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution, but you should rewrite the Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml with your custom module

**Fast Solution**:

go to your core and delete the code

> Example: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml

---

remove

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <catalog_product_index_price_reindex_all>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>0 2 * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>catalog/observer::reindexProductPrices</model>
            </run>
        </catalog_product_index_price_reindex_all>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

---

**Solution 2**:

go to */shell/indexer.php

find this code near line 154

```
        if ($this->getArg('reindex')) {
            $processes = $this->_parseIndexerString($this->getArg('reindex'));
        } else {
            $processes = $this->_parseIndexerString('all');
        }
```

comment the  `$processes = $this->_parseIndexerString('all');`

to be

```
        if ($this->getArg('reindex')) {
            $processes = $this->_parseIndexerString($this->getArg('reindex'));
        } else {
            // $processes = $this->_parseIndexerString('all');
        }
```